# How to get discord api to ignore a discord user?

Tags: python, discord.py

In the discord documentation, you would see in the a-minimal-bot section that the bot ignores its own messages. How can you do this with other discord users? (Just trying to get this question out there as I had trouble trying to figure it out)

```
@client.event    
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with other discord users, you first need need to enable [developer mode](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-) in discord. You then can copy the user's id that you want to ignore and add the .id extension after message.author like so.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == CLIENT_ID_HERE:
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by checking the user ID. Make a list of people you want to ignore using their ID

```
ignoreusers = [64987264825481, 2784687234929]


@client.event    
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user or message.author.id in ignoreusers:
        return
```